# Why the RUN command in this dockerfile is not working

Tags: linux, docker

I have a docker image (MyBaseImage) where I have Open SSH server installed. Now in the docker file, I have the following.

```
#Download base image
FROM MyBaseImage

RUN service ssh start
```

I build the new image by typing

`docker build .`

Docker builds the image fine, giving the following information.

```
Step 1/2 : FROM MyBaseImage
 ---> 56f88e347f77
Step 2/2 : RUN service ssh start
 ---> Running in a1afe0c2ce71
 * Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd                             [ OK ]
Removing intermediate container a1afe0c2ce71
 ---> 7879cebe8b6a
```

But when I run the new image by typing

`docker run -it 7879cebe8b6a`

Typing the following in the terminal of the container

`service ssh status`

gives

`* sshd is not running`

I have to then manually start the Open SSH server by typing `service ssh start`.

What could be the reason for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at your build, you can see the ssh service start in an intermediate container which is deleted in the next build step:

```
 ---> Running in a1afe0c2ce71
 * Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd                             [ OK ]
Removing intermediate container a1afe0c2ce71
```

To start a service in a Dockerfile, you should use either a `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` statement as the last line (depending on whether you might want to pass an argument in the `docker run ...` command, normally.

Generally, a service will start in the background as a daemon however, so having this as your last line:

```
CMD ["service", "ssh", "start"]
```

Will not work, as the container will exit as it has nothing do to

What you probably want (from the [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/#build-an-eg_sshd-image)) is this:

```
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Which starts the service in the foreground so that the container will stay alive

[This](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#known-issues-run) link has useful info about the difference between CMD & ENTRYPOINT, and also the difference between the exec & shell formats.

Comment: Works like a charm :) I also had to put the following before that CMD to make it work -> RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd. And of course I now use -dit instead of -it with docker run.

Answer (score -3):

Depending on which distro of linux you are using command slightly changes.

If you are using ubuntu your start command should work. 
But if your base image is centos/RHEL try `service sshd start`

Comment: I have Ubuntu 16.